# SDL/C EventHandler continuous key

Tags: c, events, sdl

I'm trying to develop an event handler in C using SDL.

I wanted to be able to detect the following things: Key pressed, key released and key held down.

The problem is that keyboard auto-repeat spams pressed keys after a certain delay and at a given interval. To mitigate this I tried using SDL_EnableKeyRepeat(0, 0); which according to documentation should disable it?

As that failed I tried mapping SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL); and it sort of works. But I'm having the issue that if i hold down a key for X seconds, it will spam ghost events for the same amount of time.

An example output from pressing esc, holding it down for a bit, and then releasing it is:

```
Pressed
HELD
HELD
HELD
... 
RELEASED       {it breaks down after first proper release}
PRESSED        
RELEASED 
HELD
PRESSED 
RELEASED 
HELD
...
RELEASED     // it always ends on released.
```

The result from above is:

```
Pressed: 18;
Released: 21;
Held: 39.

Should be:
Pressed 1;
Released 1;
Held: say 20.
```

Not sure if I'm messing up my logic somehow, or if it's something with the actual built in mechanics of keyboard events.

Here is the code:

/**
    Program Interface

```
    void ev_handle_start()      // Starts the Event Handler.
    void ev_handle_stop()       // Pauses the Event Handler.

**/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include "ev_handler.h"

#define PRESSED             1
#define RELEASED            0
#define TMR_FREQ            33
#define MOUSE_RIGHT         1
#define MOUSE_LEFT          3
#define EV_LEFT_CLICK       0
#define EV_LEFT_RELEASE     1
#define EV_RIGHT_CLICK      2
#define EV_RIGHT_RELEASE    3
#define EV_MOUSE_MAX        4
#define MAX_SCANCODES       SDL_SCANCODE_MODE
#define EV_DELAY            70

//********************************************************************************************//
//      VARIABLES
//********************************************************************************************//

SDL_Event e;
Uint8* keyboardState;
SDL_TimerID ev_timer = NULL;                // Timer to callback the search of the code
bool ev_handler_active = false;             // Used to determine if the ev_handler() is enabled or not
bool buttonState[EV_MOUSE_MAX];             // Button Stats, either pressed or released
bool evMouseEvent[EV_MOUSE_MAX];            // Used to flag if a mouse events
int evKeyEventStatus[MAX_SCANCODES];
bool evKeyStatePrev[MAX_SCANCODES];         //
bool evKeyStateCur[MAX_SCANCODES];          //

//********************************************************************************************//
//  1   FRONTEND
//********************************************************************************************//

//********************************************************************************************//
//  1.1 MOUSE
//      Can only handle left and right mouse buttons.
//********************************************************************************************//
bool evButtonPressed(int button)
{   bool flag = button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT || button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT;
    if (!flag) {
        printf("ERROR: isButtonPressed(int) received parameter of invalid type.\n");
        return false;
    }
    return buttonState[button];
}

bool evLeftClick()
{
    return evMouseEvent[EV_LEFT_CLICK];
}

bool evLeftRelease()
{
    return evMouseEvent[EV_LEFT_RELEASE];
}

bool evRightClick()
{
    return evMouseEvent[EV_RIGHT_CLICK];
}

bool evRightRelease()
{
    return evMouseEvent[EV_RIGHT_RELEASE];
}

//********************************************************************************************//
//  1.2 KEYBOARD
//********************************************************************************************//
bool evKeyHeld(SDL_Scancode sc)
{
    return evKeyEventStatus[sc] == 1 || evKeyEventStatus[sc] == 3;
}

bool evKeyPressed(SDL_Scancode sc)
{
    return evKeyEventStatus[sc] == 1;
}

bool evKeyReleased(SDL_Scancode sc)
{
    return evKeyEventStatus[sc] == 2;
}

//********************************************************************************************//
//  1.3 MANAGE
//********************************************************************************************//
void evSetup()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SCANCODES; i++) {
        evKeyStatePrev[i] = 0;
    }
    evClearEvents();
}

int j;
void evClearEvents()
{
    evMouseEvent[EV_LEFT_CLICK] = false;
    evMouseEvent[EV_LEFT_RELEASE] = false;
    evMouseEvent[EV_RIGHT_CLICK] = false;
    evMouseEvent[EV_RIGHT_RELEASE] = false;
}

//********************************************************************************************//
//  2   BACKEND
//********************************************************************************************//
void ev_handler()
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
    {
        switch (e.type)
        {
            /*Skip unnecessary events*/
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                break;

            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                buttonState[e.button.button] = PRESSED;
                if (e.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
                    evMouseEvent[EV_LEFT_CLICK] = true;
                }
                else if (e.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT) {
                    evMouseEvent[EV_RIGHT_CLICK] = true;
                }
                break;

            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                buttonState[e.button.button] = RELEASED;
                if (e.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
                    evMouseEvent[EV_LEFT_RELEASE] = true;
                }
                else if (e.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT) {
                    evMouseEvent[EV_RIGHT_RELEASE] = true;
                }
                break;

            case SDL_QUIT:
                exit(0);
                printf("Quit\n");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        keyboardState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

        for (int i = 0;  i < MAX_SCANCODES; i++)
        {
            evKeyStateCur[i]  = keyboardState[i];
            int sum = evKeyStateCur[i] + evKeyStatePrev[i]*2;
            switch (sum) {
                case  0:
                    break;

                case 1:
                    evKeyEventStatus[i] = 1;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    evKeyEventStatus[i] = 2;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    evKeyEventStatus[i] = 3;
                    break;

                default: evKeyEventStatus[i] = 0; break;
            }
            evKeyStatePrev[i] = evKeyStateCur[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of `SDL_EnableKeyRepeat`? It should return `0` on success.

Comment: it's succesful, but nothing different can be observed.

Comment: In most cases you cannot disable key repeat, but key event have `repeat` field so you can filter these events out. `SDL_GetKeyboardState` is just a reflection of past events.

Comment: you mean, event.key.repeat? Yea it removes a ghost click when you use polling, turning the found keys from: Pressed, pressed, released into pressed released.

However it does nothing to help when the key is held down, and the program spams pressed-released.

Comment: The only way i found to half succesfully do movement is: to only move when a key is being held down and counting the found held events for a specific key, resetting the counter on release and press events. It does sometime find "move" actions that are not supposed to be there from auto-keyboard events, but not very often.

Comment: Repeated events have `repeat=1`, both pressed and released. If you ignore it, there will be no spam, there is only one non-repeated event for each press/release. Perhaps I need to make previous statement more obvious - you cannot use `SDL_GetKeyboardState` for this purpose.

Comment: Here is an example of what i mean inside the main loop: http://pastebin.com/MUKBYhrj

Comment: @keltar: Yes but  the ghost repeats aren't flagged as repeats, it was the first thing i tested.  if (!e.key.repeat) printf("NOT Repeat!\n"); else printf("Repeat!\n"); This code will 99% of the time spam "Not Repeat!" when you are holding down the key. So i think it's a hardware issue.

Comment: @TiagoRedaelli probably is, as I cannot reproduce it on any of my systems. May be your keyboard have some builtin repeat rate, which probably can be disabled. If not, then you're out of luck and will have to use heuristic approach like the one you described, or even relying on timestamp in event (e.g. two close-timing release+press are both gets ignored).

Comment: But relying on timestamps or other solution brings the risk of misstaking real events for automatic ones and vice versa?

Comment: @TiagoRedaelli if there is a release and in very short time it gets pressed again - it might be completely ok to ignore both and consider key being held. Depends on what is supposed to be intended behaviour of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that SDL 2.0.4 had a bug where holding down a key sent key releases in-between key presses instead of continuous key presses. Downloading the latest version fixed the issue.

Comment: Please select your answer to accept it (add green check mark on the left). That will make clear for others that this problem is solved.